# Suppose $\dim V=200$ and $N$ is a nilpotent operator on it, and null $N^2\subset $ range $N$. Prove $N^3 \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Suppose $\dim V=200$ and $N$ is a nilpotent operator such that null $N^2\subset $ range $N$. Prove $N^3 \neq 0$

The way I consider this is by the "nonincrease" increase of the null space. That is if null $N=k$, then the increase of the next null space null $N^2 $ should be less or equal to $k$ which is to say that null $N^2\leq k+k=2k$.

Then I suppose $\dim$ null $N=k$. Thus $\dim$ range $N$= $200-k$. Thus $$\dim \text{null} N^2\leq 2k\leq 200-k\implies \dim \text{null} N^3\leq 3k \leq {200}$$ $k$ is an interger, so the inequality can just be $\dim \text{null} N^3\leq 3k<200$  This implies that the dimension of null $N^3$ will strictly be less than $200$ which implies that $N^3\neq 0$. Is this a right solution? Thank！

Comment: You know $\dim\operatorname{null}N^2\le 2k$, and you know $\dim\operatorname{null}N^2\le 200-k$. But do you really know $2k\le 200-k$?

Comment: I think maybe yes? The largest dimension of null $N^2$ is just $2k$ and its dimension should always be less or equal to the dimension of range $N$, in particular, the largest one should also be less than or equal to the dimension of range $N$. Thus I have $2k \leq 200-k$